# summing a list of numbers in dafny

Tags: dafny

I am using dafny to prove an invariant for summing a list of numbers:

```
function sum (s: seq<int>, i: int) : int {
  if |s| == 0 || i == 0 then 0 
  else s[0] + sum(s[1..], i - 1)  
}

/* 
 code: 
 cnt = 0;  
 while i < |input|
   cnt += input[i]; 
   i += 1
*/

method test (input : seq<int>, cnt : int, i : int) 
{
  // invariant: cnt = sum(input, i) && i <= |input| && i >= 0
  // prove that loop invariant is preserved:

  if cnt == sum(input, i) && i <= |input| && i >= 0 && i < |input| 
  { assert (cnt + input[i]) == sum(input, i + 1) && i+1 <= |input| && i+1 >= 0; }
}
```

dafny is unable to verify this. Am I missing as postcondition to `sum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny can do the proof, but the proof requires some induction. Therefore you must write your assertion in such a way that Dafny is provoked into attempting induction. The easiest way to do this is to write a lemma. Usually, simply writing an assertion will not cause Dafny to attempt an inductive proof.

```
function sum (s: seq<int>, i: int) : int {
  if |s| == 0 || i == 0 then 0 
  else s[0] + sum(s[1..], i - 1)  
}

lemma sumLemma(s: seq<int>, i: int)
   requires i >= 0 && i < |s|
   ensures (sum(s, i) + s[i]) == sum(s, i + 1)
{

}

/* 
 code: 
 cnt = 0;  
 while i < |input|
   cnt += input[i]; 
   i += 1
*/

method test (input : seq<int>, cnt : int, i : int) 
{
  // invariant: cnt = sum(input, i) && i <= |input| && i >= 0
  // prove that loop invariant is preserved:

  if cnt == sum(input, i) && i >= 0 && i < |input| 
  { 
      assert i+1 <= |input|;
      assert i+1 > 0;
      sumLemma(input,i);
      assert (cnt + input[i]) == sum(input, i + 1);
  }
}
```

What is happening is that, when you write the lemma Dafny guesses at what the induction step could be. If you turn Dafny's induction heuristic off then it will force you to call the induction hypothesis:

```
lemma {:induction false} sumLemma(s: seq<int>, i: int)
   requires i >= 0 && i < |s|
   ensures (sum(s, i) + s[i]) == sum(s, i + 1)
{
  if |s| == 0 || i == 0
  { } else {
    sumLemma(s[1..], i-1);
  }
}
```

What we are doing here is making an inductive argument over either the (inductive) definition of the sequence or the well founded (natural) ordering of the positive integers. You can usually think of an inductive proof as being over some well founded ordering - here we have a choice of the ordering that the tail of a sequence is smaller than the sequence, apart from the empty sequence which has no tail; or the natural ordering on the positive integers. The inductive proof technique says that you can prove some property for all elements of the ordering by:

1. proving the property for all least elements
2. proving the property for an arbitrary other element, under the assumption that the property holds for the predecessor element (we call this assumption the induction hypothesis)

So in our case, the proof has two cases:

1. The base case, either the sequence is empty or `i==0` - in which
   case we are also in the base case of the recursive function `sum`.
   Dafny easily proves this case directly by the definition of `sum`.
2. The inductive case - here we invoke the induction hypothesis. That  `sumLemma` holds for the tail of the sequence and `i-1`. Dafny can prove this case from the induction hypothesis and the definition of `sum` (you can think of this as Dafny unrolling the definition of `sum` one time).

For soundness, Dafny also has to proves that the induction itself is well founded. This corresponds to proving that the lemma `sumLemma` terminates. Dafny always proves total correctness (termination) of functions and procedures (unless you tell it not to, or in some special cases). Most of the time Dafny guess the correct termination measure, but if you ever have a case where it is unable to guess the termination measure you can supply a decreases clause.

```
lemma {:induction false} sumLemma(s: seq<int>, i: int)
   decreases s
   requires i >= 0 && i < |s|
   ensures (sum(s, i) + s[i]) == sum(s, i + 1)
```

The reason the inductive lemma and the inductively defined function are very similar in structure is that we need the base case of the induction to correspond to the base case of the induction proof in order to avoid the potential problem of having to unfold the definition of `sum` an unknown/arbitrary number of times (i.e. if the base case of the induction was some number of steps higher in the ordering than the base case of `sum`).

You may find that for some, more difficult, lemmas Dafny will fail to guess the correct induction step and you will have make the inductive call yourself anyway.

Comment: Thanks. So is the idea to write the induction step as a lemma every time when an inductive proof is needed?

Comment: Usually. Sometimes you can use a while loop instead.

Comment: Can you explain the part about turning the heuristic off? seems like you are repeating the definition of sum in the body of the lemma?

Comment: I have added some more detail, but you may also find this documentation useful: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorialcontent/Lemmas#h25